# ViewState .Add(.... or ViewState["XXXXX"] is efficient ?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, key-value, namevaluecollection

I have a reasonable dout,

`ViewState .Add(....` or `ViewState["XXXXX"]` is efficient ?

Eg.

1).

```
ViewState.Add("Example1", value );
```

2).

```
ViewState["Example1"]=value;
```

Both gives the same output, 1st one add the Value to the `NameValueCollection` if that `Key` does not exists.

2nd also does the same. Is there any difference in both. ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference as far as performance. (Any trivial check is irrelevant to all other code execution.)

`Add` *will* concatenate with existing values, however, as [per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsc9a449.aspx).

With this in mind, choose the most appropriate construct. In my mind, that is `ViewState[k] = v` in most circumstances -- unless of course the concatenation is desired.

Happy coding.